# How to convert an equation to quadratic format

Tags: quadratic-forms

How can I convert the following equation into quadratic format, e.g., $x^TQx$:

$\sum_{i=1}^n (\delta_i .x)^TA (\delta_i .x)$,

where $\delta_i$ is indicator function of size $T \times 1$, same size as $x$, $A$ is matrix of size $T \times T$, and $(\delta_i.x)$ is element-wise multiplication of two vectors.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the equation.

Comment: So $(\delta_i . x)$ is $(0,\dotsc, 0, x_i, 0,\dotsc, 0)$?

Comment: Kind of, but there could be more than one non-zero element in $\delta_i$

Comment: What is the definition of your $\delta_i$?